# Use Constant data in all Vue.js component from the API call using Mixins

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Mixins that get's the data from the sessionStorage, and that data is being used in all component and API call to get data is in the Main component(App.vue) that fetch the data and set's into the sessionStorage.

```
  beforeCreate() {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('constants')) {
       axios.get('/data').then(function(response) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('constants',JSON.stringify(response.data.result));
      });
   },
```

In the Mixins I'm not getting data from the sessionStorage, Because Mixins runs before the App.vue Component and that does not work.

I also tried to keep the fetch call inside the Mixins but, fetch call is going multiple times even though, I have the condition while getting data from sessionStorag.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const Constants = Vue.mixin({
  data() {
    const constant = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('constants'));
    return {
      get constantsData() {
        return {
          COUNTRY: constant.COUNTRY,
          STATE: constant.STATE,
        };
      },
    };
  },
});
export default Constants;
```

What is the best way to utilize Mixins with the API data. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
   beforeCreate() {
        if (!sessionStorage.getItem('constants')) {
           axios.get('/data').then(function(response) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('constants',JSON.stringify(response.data.result));
                this.constant = response.data.result;
          });
       }
```

And in mixins:

```
    import Vue from 'vue';

    const Constants = Vue.mixin({
      data() {
        return {
          constant: {}
        }
      },
    });

   export default Constants;
```

But normally I prefer using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to share data between component.

Comment: I'm using the vuex, how can I implement constant from API in vuex ?

Comment: I used method instead of the data, because, return  was calling first and before the load Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I used method in the mixins. because I'm using constant as a dropdown value (ie. country name, state from the API). I want to call method only when the dropdown component is created

```
const Constants = Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    getConstantData() {
      return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('constants'));
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
});
export default Constants;
```

and I can use getConstantData method in any component to access the data just getConstantData()